# multi database codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

Say I have 2 db configs:

```
$db['default']
$db['alternate']
```

And say I have loaded a db:

```
$this->load->db($db);
```

How can I check and see which db I've loaded?

Yes, I know you add a 2nd parameter and return the actual database, but that won't work for my current scenario.
No, I can't just do a string compare of $db (we can assume we are in a totally different method or something where I don't [and can't] have access to $db)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont know if that's any help, but you can see loaded `db` configuration by accessing eg. `$this->db->database` this will return the database name that you are currently using